# the equivalent of new Date(2011, 3, 1) in PHP

Tags: php, javascript

What is the equivalent of javascript `new Date(2011, 3, 1)` in PHP?

p.s. the output of the function above is:

```
Fri Apr 01 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST) {}
```

I have tried looking trough php DateTime Predefined Constants, but didn't find similar patern.

Comment: *(reference)* http://de2.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this:

```
echo date ("M-d-Y", mktime (0,0,0,12,32,1997));
```

More information can be found here: [mktime function manual](http://pl2.php.net/manual/pl/function.mktime.php)

You just have to use proper values in date("XXX") function. More info can be found here: [date function manual](http://pl2.php.net/manual/pl/function.date.php)

Comment: Why would you even submit this as an answer?

Comment: Does Answer mean exact solution to your problem? You asked for equivalent, doesn't it answer your question?

Comment: Clearly if that is the answer, then the solution is `D M d Y H:i:s eO (T) {}`. However, shouldn't this suppose to be a constant format value in PHP?

Comment: I think you need to use H:i:s not G. G is without leading zeros. I think you need those. From what I know there is no constant for this in PHP.

Comment: Ahhh you edited comment, or my eyes have enough monitor for today ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) you should use: [gmdate](https://www.php.net/gmdate)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$date = date_create('2011-03-01');
echo date_format($date, 'D M d Y H:i:s eO (T)');
?>
```

Formatting: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

If you want the RFC2822 standardized formatting, use `r` for the format. That would give you the format:

`Thu, 21 Dec 2000 16:01:07 +0200`

Comment: @Guy: Yes, I forgot the day number. Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    date("D M d Y H:i:s \G\M\TO (T)",strtotime('Midnight April 1st 2011'));
?>
```

Which would output `Fri Apr 01 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)` if your timezone is set correctly (in this case to `Europe/London`)

Or use mktime() or time() or a timestamp or what have you instead of strtotime().  Note that `eO (T)` in the date format won't give the same output as the java function, as if the timezone is North America/New York or whatever, then it would output something like `North America/New York-0500 (EST)` Rather than `GMT-0500 (EST)`

Can also use a DateTime object.